# Is it Possible to put image in Prompt using FormFlow in Microsofr Bot Framework?

Tags: botframework

I want to put an image in one prompt because my requirement is like that.So,Is there any way to put an image one prompt?I am using FormFlow concept to create guided bot.

[Prompt("Nice to meet you. Can I know name of your Organization? {||}")]

String organisation;

1.Nice to meet you.

2.Can I know name of your Organisation?

Above is sample of my Prompt for 'Organisation' Field.
I want to put an image before my first statement that is 'Nice to meet you'.
So,How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending [cards](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html) with attachments.
Here are some samples for [NodeJS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-RichCards) and [C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-RichCards)